# Mongoid 5 shows duplicate queries in log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Using Rails 4 and Mongoid 5.0.1

Our log output is showing almost all queries are duplicated. For a while I assumed it was just double output, but looking closer the times for execution are different, indicating it is actually sending two requests

```
d_562b2d81a54d7550ce000031.find | STARTED |  {"find"=>"deals", "filter"=>{"contact_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('563bcb9da54d75116500010b')}}
d_562b2d81a54d7550ce000031.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001186s

d_562b2d81a54d7550ce000031.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"deals", "filter"=>{"contact_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('563bcb9da54d75116500010b')}}
d_562b2d81a54d7550ce000031.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.0013s
```

This behaviour seems to apply to most queries but not all, sometimes specific queries only get called once. These seem to happen when the queries are against the database specified in the mongoid.yml and are the first in the web request.

This behaviour happens in the web request, but also any query in the Rails Console outputs two log lines too. It happens on 'where' queries, and on 'find' too

As this is a multi-tenant app, we have the following in most models:

```
store_in database: -> { Machine.current.database_name }
```

The collection for Machine (along with Users) is stored in the master_#{Rails.env} database

The duplicate requests (in the logs) are all against the correct databases though, so this might be a red herring.

When we were on Mongoid 3 this problem was never apparent, but Mongoid 5 has significantly better logging, so the problem may have existed then too but not been noticed.

Comment: Hi, I've noticed this as well, any progress on this, I'm seeing 5 queries find the same record while performing an update

Comment: Nope, none - still see 2 queries

Answer (score 0):

Actually I suspect it's a gem called `bullet` causing the duplicate logs. Turning it off solve my problems.